# Compatibility is not changing while restoring it to a latest SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

Is it possible to do one of the following:

1. Change the compatibility of a database in restoring status from 100 to 130? or
2. Restore a database with a compatibility level of 100 in the latest database server with a compatibility of 100?

The reason we need to do this is that we currently have a database with a compatibility level of 100 that we want to take a backup of, then restore to two new instances and set up mirroring. Both new instances need to be compatibility level 130.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to change the compatibility of a database after restoring to a supported compatibility level. Compatibility level `130` supports the compatibility levels `130`, `120`, `110`, `100`.

Simply execute this script after restoring the database:

```
ALTER DATABASE <database name>
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = -- pick compatibility level 140 | 130 | 120 | 110 | 100 | 90
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that and that works.. However is there any option that I could use to get the compatibility upgraded while the latest 2014/2016 sql server?